# how to get the storyboard interface setting in Xcode 14.2.3?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have been wanting to create a small project using Xcode 14.2.3 but can't find the user interface setting so that I can add the storyboard setting and complete my project.
Please help

I tried to make a new project on Xcode and add the storyboard setting but couldn't get that option unlike the older version of Xcode used to provide

Comment: What is "the user interface setting"? What are you referring to? What does this setting control?

Comment: If you create a new SwiftUI project  you aren’t able to choose a storyboard interface because storyboards are for UIKit projects. You can add a storyboard to your project later if you want to use it for some UIKit view controllers in your project. Alternatively you could create a UIKit-based project and add SwiftUI views where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new project in Xcode 14, the following sheet opens:

[image]

Notice the categories at the top of the sheet: Multiplatform, iOS, macOS, watchOS, and so on.

If you click Multiplatform at the top of the sheet and choose the App or Document App project templates, you create a SwiftUI project. SwiftUI projects do not use storyboards so there will be no Interface menu to choose SwiftUI or storyboard for the user interface.

To use a storyboard for your project, click iOS (or Mac) at the top of the sheet, like in the screenshot, choose the App or Document App project template, and click the Next button. When you do that, you will see an Interface menu, where you can choose to use a storyboard.